# Is overriding a parent class method with a different signature a good practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this small example with parent/child classes. I know the code will run without problem, but is it a good practice to override a parent's method with a method which has a different signature? PyCharm does not seem to think it is a good idea:

> Signature of method 'Daughter.do()' does not match signature of base method in class 'Mother'

For information, calling ***Parent*** method ***do*** should execute ***do(self)*** not ***do(self, c)***.

Code example:

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = "a"

    def do(self):
        print("Parent: {}".format(self._a))


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self._b = "b"

    def do(self, c):
        print("Child: {}".format(self._a))
        print("Child: {}".format(self._b))
        print("Child: {}".format(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice. It for example breaks [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); If you have a function, that expects a `Mother` instance, and calls `do()` on it, it will fail when you pass a `Daughter` to it.

See this example:

```
def call_do(mother: Mother) -> None:
     mother.do()
```

You *should* be able to pass an instance of `Mother`, **or an instance of any of its subclasses** into `call_do`.

But if you now do:

```
daughter = Daughter()
call_do(daughter)
```

you will get a `TypeError`.